# Renaming files based on a CSV file

Tags: python

I have a set of images in a folder with the names as shown under the "old_name' header in a CSV file. I have to rename each of these images to the corresponding "new_name" and save them in a different folder.

[image]

Comment: this has nothing to do with image processing or OpenCV. use tags responsibly. please also take the [tour]; you don't have the "Informed" badge yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options for moving/renaming a file:

shutil.move()

os.rename()

Let's look at shutil.move():

```
    import shutil

with open("fileNames.csv") as fi:
    alumnos = []
    ln = fi.readline() # No Process Headers
    ln = fi.readline()
    while ln != "":
        old_name, new_name = ln.replace("\n", "").split(",")
        shutil.move(old_name, new_name)
        ln = fi.readline()
```

Let's look at os.rename():

```
    import os

with open("fileNames.csv") as fi:
    alumnos = []
    ln = fi.readline() # Skip first line to No Process Headers
    ln = fi.readline()
    while ln != "":
        old_name, new_name = ln.replace("\n", "").split(",")
        
        os.rename(old_name, new_name)
        ln = fi.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to read the file using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("file_name.csv")
```

then set your names as lists

```
old_names = list(data["old_names"])
new_names = list(data["new_names"])
```

then you can go through your folder and check each file name

```
import os
for file, index in zip(os.listdir("my_directory"), range(len(os.listdir("my_directory"))):
    os.rename(old_name[index], new_name[index])
```

Comment: You don't *need* to use pandas to read a CSV.

Comment: It can be done in several ways, I did with pandas